# How do you print the data after the key in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the keys and the values within each key and alert them to the console. I got the keys to print out on the screen, but I am not able to print out the items after the keys?
Here is my JSON file:

```
{
   "item1":  "I'm loving it",
   "item2": "Fan food, not fast food",
   "item3": "Eat fresh",
   "item4": "It's finger likin good",
   "item5": "Have it your way"      
}
```

Does anyone know how to print like the "I'm loving it part"?
Here is my code for printing the keys:

```
function extractQuotes(data)
           {  
              data = JSON.parse(data); 
              alert(Object.keys(data)); 
           }
```

```
function init()
           {
              var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
              request.open("GET", "items.json");
              request.onload = function(){
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                extractQuotes(request.responseText);//responseText is the json data (quotes)
             }   
           };    
              request.send(null);
           }
```

Comment: `Object.values()`

Comment: `Object.entries()` read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

will give you both+

Comment: I tried doing this:  console.log(Object.values(data[1]));  to get the first value of the json file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Is this how the line would look? console.log(Object.values(data[1]));

Comment: use Object.entries(), then iterate from result to get keys and values something like for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

Answer (score 0):

This should help if you want to alert only the values as an array,

```
function extractQuotes(data) {
  alert(Object.values(JSON.parse(data)));
}
```

Output:

```
[
  "I'm loving it",
  'Fan food, not fast food',
  'Eat fresh',
  "It's finger likin good",
  'Have it your way'
]
```